# Oracle query to find any special character in first position or end position of the field value

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in Oracle database with special characters attached at first and last position in the field value. I want to eliminate those special characters while querying the table. I have used INSTR function but I had to apply for each and every special character using CASE expression.
Is there a way to eliminate any special characters that is attached only at first and last positions in one shot?

The query I am using as is below:
CASE WHEN
INSTR(emp_address,'"')=1 THEN REPLACE((emp_address,'"', '').
.
.
.

Comment: What are you defining as a "special" character, and can you include some sample address data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to replace the leading and trailing character of a string if they match the regular expression pattern. For example, if your definition of a "special character" is anything that is not an alpha-numeric character then you can use the regular expression:

- `^` the start-of-the-string then
- `[^[:alnum:]]` any single character that does not match the POSIX alpha-numeric character group
- `|` or
- `[^[:alnum:]]` any single character that does not match the POSIX alpha-numeric character group then
- `$` the end-of-the-string.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT emp_address,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         emp_address,
         '^[^[:alnum:]]|[^[:alnum:]]$'
       ) AS simplified_emp_address
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (emp_address) AS
SELECT 'test' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '"test2"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Not "this" one' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMP_ADDRESS | SIMPLIFIED_EMP_ADDRESS |
> | --- | --- |
> | test | test |
> | "test2" | test2 |
> | Not "this" one | Not "this" one |

If you have a more complicated definition of a special character then change the regular expression appropriately.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9b4a663aa639bcc4b0fc48222dce1076)*